# 'There was an error uploading the file' php file to web server, error on line 5 & 6

Tags: php, file, upload, localhost, webserver

I would really appreciate if someone could help me here, I am quite the noob with php or any of this stuff.

I am trying to upload a php file. I have tried both localhost and a web server and I get the same error in both.
This is the error from the web server, on localhost it doesn't specify which lines.

> Notice: Undefined index: image in >/storage/ssd4/613/5272613/public_html/hq.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in >/storage/ssd4/613/5272613/public_html/hq.php on line 6
>   There was an error uploading the file

The first 12 lines of my code look like this:

```
<?php

//UPLOAD IMAGE TO SERVER
$target_path = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
if (filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) > 1000 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    //echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image']['name'])." has been uploaded\n";
} else {
    die("There was an error uploading the file\n");
}
```

I believe the error should be inside there somewhere, as I said I am really stuck and have no clue how to advance here. Any input would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Can we see your form?..

Comment: Hi Lawrence, thanks for the quick reply but I am not sure what form you are talking about... As I said I am very new and this code was not made by me.

Comment: Its always a good idea to do a search before asking a quesiton

Comment: The `<form></form>` bit in your HTML.

Comment: Hi Riggs, I made sure to search around for an hour but none of the answers I found really brought me any further..

Comment: Google `Notice: Undefined index` and you get the answer I dup's this quesiton with as the first search result